# Which CMSs are for mobile?

Tags: mobile, content-management-system

I just curious if there are any CMS is made for web and mobile use.

Preferably PHP-CMS.

Is there anyone knows about it?

Comment: What do you mean? In most systems you can alter the templates to work with mobile browsers, or do you mean the content authoring parts?

Answer (score 1):

Any fully functional web content management system ought to be able to generate output suitable for mobile devices. If you come across a WCMS that can't do this, you should immediately exclude it from consideration.

Basically, the only real difference between web content for desktop browsers and mobile devices is that you might want to generate slightly different text output. It's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

This will be somewhat [controversial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105648/wordpress-is-it-a-cms), as some people don't believe WordPress is a CMS..

But if you're looking for simplicity...

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-edition/

Answer (score 0):

Percussion CMS is Web 2.0, engaging your on-line community providing rss feeds, taxonomy, ratings, community forums. The system also allows end-users to publish, modify and create content easily to multi-channels. Systems are also scalable and easy to integrate.